# Nodejs out of memory error with string operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, v8

Given a string `s`, allocate it `n` times for a length of x. Example: if `n = 7` and `s = "ada"`, then the final string is `adaadaa`. Finally, count the number of `a`s in the string.

My solution can be found below. It works fine except it reaches a `API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory` error when `n = 10000000` or more.

Why is this? What is it about string operations in javascript that causes it to run out of memory if `n=100000` works just fine? Is it related to how the engine tries to give it a type of int whereas it should be a long?

```
const s = "a";
const n = 100000000;

let count = 0;
let output = "";
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (count % s.length == 0) {
        count = 0;
    }
    output += s[count];
    count++;
}

let finalCount = 0;
let arr = output.split('');
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 'a') {
        finalCount++;
    }
}

console.log(finalCount);
```

Comment: Don't create that `output` at all. Just count `a`s. Write a clever algorithm, don't hog memory.

Comment: this is just an example, your solution would not work for other kinds of input. And that's what I'm doing now ;)

Comment: try `output.match(/[a]/ig)||[]).length` instead of looping maybe

Comment: What do you mean by "*other kinds of inputs*"? The exercise given in your first paragraph can be solved without allocating more than a constant amount of memory. Or do you mean it is just an "example exercise"?

Comment: @MancharyManchaary The loop over `output` is not what causes the out-of-memory exception

Comment: You ran out of memory, do the math. 10,000,000 bytes / 1024 (to MB) / 1024 (to GB) = 9.53 GB ...

Comment: How did you install node?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: `stimesn = (s,n) => Array.from({ [Symbol.iterator]: function*(){ for(let i = 0; i < n; ++i) yield s[i % s.length]; } }).join(''); stimesn("ada",10); // "adaadaadaa"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is it about string operations in javascript that causes it to run out of memory?

You simply are building a gigantic, enormous string. Such a string needs to reside in memory somewhere. Your string is too large.

You can optimise the algorithm so that it doesn't need a that large string (in this particular example, I would even consider it a *simplification* as well):

```
const s = "a";
const n = 100000000;

let count = 0;
let finalCount = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (count % s.length == 0) {
        count = 0;
    }
    if (s[count] == 'a') {
        finalCount++;
    }
    count++;
}

console.log(finalCount);
```

(You can further optimise so that it doesn't need a loop until `n` but runs in `O(s.length)`, but that isn't necessary to reduce memory usage).

Comment: Thank you. I feel I have a better understanding of strings and memory handling after this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can also increase the max memory size for nodejs it is by default set to 1 gb, see the link below on how to increase the size. You have hit the limit, its a nodejs limit not a javascript one.

https://medium.com/@vuongtran/how-to-solve-process-out-of-memory-in-node-js-5f0de8f8464c

also,
In your first for loop you have an if statement checking if count(which equals 1 after the first loop) divided by 1 has a remainder of 1, if it does, it sets count to 0 and then adds an 'a' to the output and then sets count to 1 to cause the entire loop to run again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I agree that a better implementation of the algorithm could be made, rather than messing with the memory limits of the nodejs engine.